# Error accessing property across classes: an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been dabbling in unity and have run into a problem as I an unable to figure out how to notify another class that a ability has been used and the countdown is active. I realize that it is because I need to be making a static reference but not quite sure how to use one while still being able to change the value. I will include just the important bits so that you don't have to waste your time. (I want to be able to have the usedAbilities.canFireballnow be equal to that as when I call it in the fireball script.)

**fireball**

```
float canuseFireballtimer = 0;
bool startCooldown = false;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (startCooldown) {
        usedAbilities.canFireballnow = false; // error
        canuseFireballtimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (canuseFireballtimer >= 5) {
            usedAbilities.canFireballnow = true; //error
        }
    }
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && enoughmana && usedAbilities.canFireballnow) { // error
       
        startCooldown = true;
       
        ManaBar.mana -= 10f;
        Instantiate(fireballPrefab, fireballSpawn.position, fireballSpawn.rotation);
    }
}
```

**usedAbilities script**

```
public bool canFireballnow = true;
```

Thanks,
A fellow Programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add a reference to your object. You can do that by using [SerializeField] before creating a variable of type GameObject. Like this:

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject obj;
```

Then, in Unity, you can drag the GameObject from the Hierarchy to the Inspector.
This is what you should see in the Inspector:

[image: a gameobject dragged into inspector field]

Then, you need to get the script component of the GameObject to finally be able to read it's value.

```
obj.GetComponent<name_of_your_script>().value;
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject abilities;

void Update() {
    if (canuseFireballtimer >= 5) {
        abilities.GetComponent<usedAbilities>().canFireballnow = true;
    }
```

Note: Your variable should be public.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I was just wondering what a serialize field is and how I would get this to work across multiple classes. Thanks

Comment: In Unity, a serialized field is a field that appears in the Inspector when viewing the script component. Public variables are serialized by default. However, it's good practice to keep as many variables private as possible, so instead we declare the GameObject as a private variable and force Unity to serialize it using [SerializeField].